# 'object not found' error on build (bookdown), but the same code runs in the console

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, bookdown, ggpubr

I'm trying to build a book which includes the following code

```
ggdotchart(themes, x = "theme", y = "citations",          # requires `easyGgplot2`, `ggplot2`, `ggpubr` 
            color = "#440154",                                # Color by groups
            palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"), # Custom color palette
            sorting = "descending",                       # Sort value in descending order
            add = "segments",                             # Add segments from y = 0 to dots
            rotate = TRUE,                                # Rotate vertically
            dot.size = 9,                                 # Large dot size
            label = round(themes$citations),                        # Add citations values as dot labels
            font.label = list(color = "white", size = 10, 
                              vjust = 0.5),               # Adjust label parameters
            ggtheme = theme_pubr(),                        # ggplot2 theme
            ylab="Citation Count",
            xlab="Theme"
 )
```

When I run the code in the console, I get the following graphic:

[image]

But when I knit I get this error:

```
Quitting from lines 28-42 (bookdown-demo.Rmd) 
Error in ggdotchart(themes, x = "theme", y = "citations", color = "#440154",  : 
  could not find function "ggdotchart"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval
In addition: Warning message:
In xfun::prose_index(x) : Code fences are not balanced
Execution halted
```

or when I build, I get the following error:

```
Quitting from lines 54-68 (bookdown-demo.Rmd) 
Error in ggdotchart(themes, x = "theme", y = "citations", color = "#440154",  : 
  object 'themes' not found
Calls: local ... eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> ggdotchart
Execution halted
Error: bookdown::render_book() failed to render the output format 'bookdown::gitbook'.
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

I've tried `themes$citations <- as.character(themes$citations)` and

```
load("themes.RData")
```

I'm using a new copy of the [Bookdown template repo](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo). [My repo is here.](https://github.com/cmadland/asmt-test)

Please let me know if there is any other context I should add here.

Colin

Comment: A Rmd is rendered in a fresh R session, i.e. objects which exist only in your global environment (as your `themes` dataframe) are not available when rendering your book. You have to import or create all data which you want to use in your Rmd. The same is true for functions from packages. You have to attach all packages using `library()` in your Rmd.

Comment: Thanks @stefan. I have the packages loaded but I'm missing what more i need to do for the dataframe. I imported from csv and `themes` shows in the environment tab, but how do I make that accessible within the rmd?

Comment: Add the command you used to import the csv to your Rmd.

Comment: There we go! Thank you so much.

added `readr` to list of required packages, then 
`themes <- read_csv("themes.csv")` to the Rmd file, and all is building!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @stefan for getting me on the right track on this.

Here are the key points, and apparently this is a common problem for those starting out with rMarkdown and bookdown.

- RStudio renders .Rmd files in a new R session, meaning none of the objects or functions you have loaded in your environment are accessible when you knit or build; hence the errors I was seeing.

  - to load packages, use `library(package)` or `require(package)` in your index.Rmd file

    - make sure you load or require the package `readr`, or `tidyverse`
  - to load data, use `dataframe <- read_csv("path/to/file.csv")` to load the data you need into an object called dataframe (or whatever suits your fancy). This will create a tibble that is accessible to R chunks in your .Rmd.
- I accomplished all this with the following R chunk on my index.Rmd...

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
require(ggplot2)
require(easyGgplot2)
require(ggpubr)
require(readr)
pubdate <- read_csv("data/pubdate.csv")
themes <- read_csv("data/themes.csv")
```

It is quite possible I am missing some nuance, or that there are more parsimonious solutions, and I'd be happy to hear from you.